Difference Between GA4 Property Tracking and UA Property Tracking
I use UA Property Tracking in SFMC, which automatically adds UTM tags like utm_source, utm_medium, and utm_campaign to email links. In contrast, GA4 Property Tracking lacks these tags and only adds journey-specific parameters like sfmc_journey_id.
SFMC encourages switching to GA4, but I have a few questions:

Does using UA Property Tracking affect GA dashboards in SFMC Journey Builder? I don't see the dashboard at all.
Is there any risk in sticking with UA Property Tracking despite Google discontinuing UA?
Can GA4 Property Tracking automate classic UTM tags like utm_source, or must they be added manually?


You would use WAC to track any desired UTM tags outside the journey-specific tags.
The GA4/UA integration inside MCE is designed just to pull data onto the journey canvas from GA for those sends.
WAC would solve anyother use case.

Can I have both WAC and GA4 property tracking enabled? Will the UTM tags conflict with each other? Also, in GA4, could the tracking be disrupted due to the increased number of UTM tags?
If I don’t use WAC and therefore don’t have utm_source and utm_medium (since GA4 property tracking doesn’t add them), how would GA4 track that the traffic is coming from SFMC in that case? Does GA4 always require WAC as well?
